# WordPress search in backend - post type only searchable in its own "type"?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I just had a realisation that in my backend I can search everything in every search field. IE. I have a custom post type called Recipe, which is searchable in the normal Post search area (purely in the back-end). Is there any way to make sure you can only search for the given taxonomy within the post type, custom or not? And also being able to do this, but still search on the front-end, and get results for everything at once?

My function for the search is as follows:

```
function ScanWPostFilter($query) {
  if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', array('post','product','recipe', 'page'));
      $query->set('orderby', array('relevance' => 'DESC', 'type' => 'ASC'));
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','ScanWPostFilter');
```

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the search to a specific taxonomy within the post type in the backend, you can modify the `ScanWPostFilter` function as follows:

```
function ScanWPostFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) {
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy', // Replace with your actual taxonomy slug
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $query->query_vars['s']
            )
        );
        $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','ScanWPostFilter');
```

Replace `'your_taxonomy'` with the actual taxonomy slug you want to search within.

Comment: This works very well in the back-end! But on the front-end search it displays nothing, what gives?

Comment: Did you Replace 'your_taxonomy' with the actual taxonomy?

Comment: Yes, and it worked in the back-end, I was able to search the given custom post only "on" the given custom post search bar in the back-end, but nothing would be shown on the front

Comment: Can you share URL and what term you are using to search?

Comment: It's for a client - is there any way I can send it in private?

Comment: check my profile. You will know.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
function ScanWPostFilter($query) {
  if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', array('post','product','recipe', 'page'));
      $query->set('orderby', array('relevance' => 'DESC', 'type' => 'ASC'));
      $taxquery = array(
         'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
               'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => array( 1, 2, 3 ),
               'operator'=> 'IN'
          ),
          array(
               'taxonomy' => 'category',
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => array( 1, 2, 3 ),
               'operator'=> 'IN'
          )
     );
     $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','ScanWPostFilter');
```

Comment: Hmm, so adding the post_types as taxonomy, ye? If so, I cannot get any search results by doing so!

Comment: @Dannie I didn't add the post_types as taxonomy? I'm adding the taxonomies as taxonomies and adding the post types as post types.

Comment: Hmm, I have no luck getting it to work - no matter what I change (or try to) all search is dead. Might be I'm missing something crucial in the understanding of it